# Highlighting docker commands in vim

Tags: vim, docker

I am editing Dockerfile on command line. 
I would like to know how could I make Docker's command to be recognized by vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker GitHub repository contains a dockerfile.vim that provides syntax highlighting for Dockerfiles:

https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/contrib/syntax/vim

Answer (score 4):

There is another popular plugin for Vim:
https://github.com/ekalinin/Dockerfile.vim

Comment: How does the official plugin differ from this one?

Comment: It recognizes Dockerfile even if it has an extension. E.g., the built-in highlighter won't recognize `Dockerfile.prod` and this plugin will.

Comment: If you want to use the official dockerfile plugin just add this to your .vimrc https://github.com/jmera/dotfiles/commit/7390b649f6dffff3ec3f82ef6ff5e7812ef9dee6

Comment: @silentser this is a huge benefit; I came exactly searching for how to get vim to recognize `Dockerfile.something`